# How to mask an image in OpenCV. Then invert the image into a binary array

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv

I have come quite far in this opencv/tensorflow journey! I'm totally new to tensor flow and opencv, and gotten this far. Here's where I am currently stuck. Appreciate the help!

So I have an image. I am using Tensorflow for the object detection, and I'm using open CV to draw the box on the image.

[image]

What I'm looking to do now is to basically fill the detected object with one color and everything outside of it with another. For example, something like this:

[image]

Finally, I'm looking to map the image in a binary array based on color. So something like "Blue is 1" and "Green is 0" to feed into a graph algorithm for further processing.

Here is my code so far:

```
 def annotate_objects(annotator, results, labels, npcv, count):
  window_name = 'Image'
  image = npcv
  filename="image"
  filename+=str(count)
  filename+=".jpg"
  for obj in results:
    # Convert the bounding box figures from relative coordinates
    # to absolute coordinates based on the original resolution

    height, width, channels = image.shape
    print("Image height,", height, "Image width ", width)
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = obj['bounding_box']
    xmin = int(xmin * width)
    xmax = int(xmax * width)
    ymin = int(ymin * height)
    ymax = int(ymax * height)

    if obj['score'] >= 0.60:
      start_point = (xmin,ymin)

      end_point = (xmax,ymax) 

      color = (255, 0, 0) 
      thickness = 5


      image = cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

      font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
      yminT = ymin

      yminT += 50

      org = (xmin, yminT)

      fontScale = 0.5

      color = (255, 0, 0) 
      text = labels[obj['class_id']]


      thickness = 2

      image = cv2.putText(image, text , org, font,  
                   fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)


    # Overlay the box, label, and score on the camera preview
    annotator.bounding_box([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
    annotator.text([xmin, ymin],
                   '%s\n%.2f' % (labels[obj['class_id']], obj['score']))

    print(labels[obj['class_id']], obj['score'])
    print(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
  cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

Comment: Create a green matrix (or any other background color) an draw a filled rectangle there same size and position as your tracked bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the rectangle on a blank image with `thickness=-1`:

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=image.dtype)
mask = cv2.rectangle(mask, start_point, end_point, 255, -1)
```

Comment: Ok, I noticed that this mask turns the object black and the outside area white. Which is ok, I can work with that. How would I invert the mask and create binary array that represents 1 as black and 0 is white?

Comment: Actually maybe inverting is the wrong term, basically I'm trying to create an array where 1 is black and 0 is white